# PhantomJS does not run JavaScript code

Tags: laravel-5, phantomjs, codeception

I'm using Laravel with Vagrant. I need to run acceptance test using Codeception and PhantomJS. Everything seems to be fine except running JS code.

I have a registration form that uses a little JS code to prevent robots from registration:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $('.form-horizontal').append('<input type="checkbox" name="human" value="1" checked="checked">');
        });
    </script>
```

This is what I do.

1) I run phantomjs:

`B# phantomjs --webdriver=5555`

2) Start acceptance test:

`vendor/bin/codecept run acceptance RegisterCept`

Of course test fails because PhantomJS does not execute JS code and without it registration can not be completed. What am I doing wrong? Config file:

```
class_name: AcceptanceTester
modules:
    enabled:
        - WebDriver:
            url: http://localhost
            browser: phantomjs
            port: 4444
            capabilities:
                javascriptEnabled: true
                webStorageEnabled: true
                unexpectedAlertBehaviour: 'accept'
        - Laravel5:
            environment_file: .env.testing
        - \Helper\Acceptance
```

I'm using Travis. Test also fails. My .travis.yml:

```
language: php
php:
  - 5.5
  - 5.6

services: postgresql

addons:
  postgresql: "9.3"

install:
  - composer install

before_script:
  - cp .env.testing .env
  - php artisan migrate --seed --env="testing"
  - php vendor/bin/codecept build
  - phantomjs --webdriver=4444 2>&1 >/dev/null &
  - sleep 5

script: php vendor/bin/codecept run
```

My test:

```
<?php
$I = new AcceptanceTester($scenario);
$I->wantTo('register a user');

$I->amOnPage('/Register');
$I->wait(1);
$I->fillField('name', 'Joe Doe');
$I->fillField('email', 'example@example.com');
$I->fillField('password', 'password');
$I->fillField('password_confirmation', 'password');
$I->click('button[type=submit]');

$I->amOnPage('/');
$I->see('Joe Doe');
```

Comment: *"PhantomJS does not execute JS code"* of course it does. That's why it is preferable to scrapers like mechanize if JavaScript is involved. The problem is probably that it can't open a page on localhost. Try it with `127.0.0.1`.

Comment: Thank you but still no luck. I know that PhantomJS supports JavaScript. It just does not work in my case. I'm sure I'm missing something...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you enabled both Laravel5 and WebDriver modules in the same suite.

It has been a common issue recently - https://github.com/Codeception/Codeception/issues/2435

Functional actions in your suite are executed by Laravel5 module which does not support javascript. Solution is to disable Laravel5 module.

Comment: Yes, yes, yes!! You made my day :)